# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: return type mismatch in function declared to return integer;

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to Create SQL a function in Amazon Redshift.

Please tell me why am I getting this error and how can I solve the same:

> > error: Amazon Invalid operation: return type mismatch in function declared to return integer;

My code is:

```
create function calc_age (varchar)
returns int
stable
AS $$   
    select DATEDIFF(YY,to_date(substring($1,1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'),to_date(GETDATE(),'yyyy-mm-dd'))
$$ Language sql;
```

Comment: I guess the error is clear, your return value in the function is set to `int` but it doesn't seem that you're returning an `int` in your `sql` function.

Comment: @PaulKaram DATEDIFF is an inbuilt function of SQL and it returns int. **source** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

Comment: @shaazmanjiyani: why are you quoting (or reading) the **Microsoft SQL Server** manual if you are using Amazon Redshift. Those are two **very** different database systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Amazon's redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html), `DATEDIFF` function return type is `BIGINT`.

I would suggest you try to convert that to `INT` using the following query:

```
select CONVERT(integer, DATEDIFF(YY,to_date(substring($1,1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'),to_date(GETDATE(),'yyyy-mm-dd')))
```

To read more about the `CONVERT` function, check [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html)

Comment: No problem at all. Make sure to differentiate between the return type you choose and the return type other functions return therefor you can evade such problems in the future.

Comment: @shaazmanjiyani It would be nice to accept an answer if it solved your question and worked for you to let others know and save their time.